# jQuery DataTables Ajax GET json formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

I am using JQuery DataTables to show tabular data.

I am using the following code for the GET ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#data_table').DataTable( {
    ajax: {
        type: 'GET',
        url: url_path,
        data: {'data_id':data_id},
        success: function(data) {
            #here is where I am not sure how to populate the table with the data
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $.each(data[i], function(name, value) {
                    console.log(name + ": " + value);
                });
            }
        }
    }
} );
```

example console output:

```
>>obj1_property1: value1 #to go in table row 1 column 1
>>obj1_property2: value2 #to go in table row 1 column 2
>>obj2_property1: value1 #to go in table row 2 column 1
>>obj3_property2: value2 #to go in table row 2 column 2
```

From the ajax request I get an array of objects and I can get their name and value properties from the code inside the success function. But I can't work out how to populate the DataTable with this data.

The example I have found here: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html shows to use:

```
"ajax": "data/objects.txt",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name" },
```

But I can't work out how to tailor this to the specific example I have provided - where and how would I specify 'columns' in my example returning an array of objects?

Comment: Does you returned json of the format { "data": [ ... your objects here ...] }   From your example output it doesn't look that way.

Comment: @backpackcoder with code as above output is of the form proprty1: value1, if I replace the code in the success function with: console.log(data) I get [Object, Object, Object]  each of these objects should represent a row. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add the `columns` option with the [data option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) to you Datatables initialization option.  You also will need to return JSON that is a single object with your data array contained in the "data" field (see below).  Also remove the `success` option from the `ajax` option since that requires you to explicitly make a call to draw the table.  It's used if you need to post process data from a request.  This fiddle should help https://jsfiddle.net/backpackcoder/fv95dzxs/.  Because I used post for the `/echo/json` call, my ajax data object puts the returned JSON in the `data` param instead of your id.

You'll want you're returned data to have this format.

```
{
    "data": [{
      "col1": "data1",
      "col2": "data2",
      "col3": "data3",
    }, {
      "col1": "data4",
      "col2": "data5",
      "col3": "data6",
    }]
  }
```